# Flash Player not working in IE 11 Windows 8 Mode

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer, flash

I am having an issue with Flash Player acting strangely. Originally, the problem was occurring in both IE 11 desktop and Windows 8.1 (app) mode. I posted a question about this on Microsoft Answers and it was suggested that I uninstall and reinstall the `KB2957689` update, and that's what I did. Following the reinstall, Flash started working again in IE 11 Desktop mode, but it is still not working in app mode. What can I do about this? I use Windows 8.1 Update 1 Pro x64.

Adobe Flash Player test page in IE 11 Desktop mode.
[image: Desktop Mode]

Adobe Flash Player test page in IE 11 Windows 8.1 (App) Mode.
[image: Windows 8.1 (App) Mode]

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean "not possible to use IE on Windows 8"? IE came with Windows 8.

Comment: @Ramhound I removed all references to Windows 8 to eliminate confusion. I'm sorry about that, as I tend to use Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 interchangeably even though I am aware of their differences.

Comment: I have provided an explaination for this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash by default only works on certain websites within IE11 while in Modern UI mode.

The process to enable Flash on any website is pretty straight forward.  The tutorials I found reference IE10 since nothing has changed in that regard with the release of IE11 the instructions are still valid.

**Microsoft uses a compatibility file to determine if Flash is turned on or off on a domain in Internet Explorer 11. All that needs to be done is to add domains to the list to add support for Flash.**

So you need to disable this list from being updated.

1. Open the desktop version of Internet Explorer 11.
2. Press the Alt key to bring up the menu bar, and select Tools > Compatibility View Settings from the menu.
3. Locate the preference "Download updated compatibility lists from Microsoft" and uncheck it.
4. Close the menu and the browser when you are done.

[image]

The file which contains the whitelist is an XML file.  This file that you need to edit is located here: 
`C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata.xml`

> Replace [USER_NAME] with the name of the user who is signed in
>   currently. I recommend opening the file in a plain text editor such as
>   Notepad.
>
> Locate  in the document which marks the beginning of the domain
>   list that Flash contents are enabled on.

The quickest way to edit this file is to run the following `run` command

```
notepad “%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata.xml”
```

To add domains to the list simply use the following syntax:

adobe.com

Append each entry to the whitelist, for instance right before the closing .  Be sure both the x64 and x86 platforms are added to your new whitelisted domain.

[image]

The last step is you should delete your Modern UI browsing history.

1. Open the start screen version of Internet Explorer 11
2. Press Windows-I to open the settings
3. Select Internet Options > Delete browsing history

[Source 1](http://betanews.com/2012/11/06/add-internet-explorer-10-flash-support-for-any-domain-on-windows-8/)
[Source 2](http://www.howtogeek.com/127787/how-to-use-flash-on-any-website-in-modern-internet-explorer-10/)